# Thumbor -- Supervisor process exiting loop "exit status 1; not expected" - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, thumbor

I am trying to start up thumbor using supervisor and have been following [this guide](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/wiki/Hosting).

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 on an EC2 instance (if that matters).

I have installed all the necessary packages and everything seemed to be working fine until I checked the logs:

`sudo service supervisor status`

```
● supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-08-07 16:17:24 UTC; 16min ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 7774 ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7851 (supervisord)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 103.2M
      CPU: 11min 20.403s
   CGroup: /system.slice/supervisor.service
           ├─ 7851 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
           ├─17956 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/thumbor --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8000 --conf=/etc/thumbor8000.conf
           ├─17957 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/thumbor --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8001 --conf=/etc/thumbor8001.conf
           ├─17958 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/thumbor --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8002 --conf=/etc/thumbor8002.conf
           └─17959 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/thumbor --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8003 --conf=/etc/thumbor8003.conf

2017-08-07 17:02:12,741 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8000' with pid 2551
2017-08-07 17:02:12,743 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8001' with pid 2552
2017-08-07 17:02:12,745 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8002' with pid 2553
2017-08-07 17:02:12,751 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8003' with pid 2554
2017-08-07 17:02:13,742 INFO success: thumbor8000 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,742 INFO success: thumbor8001 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,746 INFO success: thumbor8002 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,754 INFO success: thumbor8003 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,842 INFO exited: thumbor8001 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,843 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8001' with pid 2567
2017-08-07 17:02:13,845 INFO exited: thumbor8002 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,847 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8002' with pid 2568
2017-08-07 17:02:13,848 INFO exited: thumbor8003 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:13,850 INFO exited: thumbor8000 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:14,331 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8000' with pid 2575
2017-08-07 17:02:14,333 INFO spawned: 'thumbor8003' with pid 2576
2017-08-07 17:02:14,457 INFO exited: thumbor8002 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:14,466 INFO exited: thumbor8001 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:14,941 INFO exited: thumbor8003 (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-08-07 17:02:14,943 INFO exited: thumbor8000 (exit status 1; not expected)
```

My `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/thumbor.conf` is as follows:

```
command=thumbor --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=800%(process_num)s --conf=/etc/thumbor800%(process_num)s.conf
process_name=thumbor800%(process_num)s
numprocs=4
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stopsignal=TERM
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/thumbor800%(process_num)s.stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/thumbor800%(process_num)s.stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
```

The `INFO exited: thumbor800x (exit status 1; not expected)` continues and keeps running until I stop.

When I try to visit the IP I receive a `took too long to respond` message and is timed out.

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with the thumbor portion is as follows as well inside the `http {}` block:

```
        upstream thumbor {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my_ec2_ip.compute.amazonaws.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://thumbor;
        }
}
```

I had to comment out the original `sites-enabled` server port to get this part to work.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am fairly new to this so hopefully it is something small I missed.

If I am missing any other info to diagnose please let me know.

Comment: smh stumbled upon a similar issue with nginx-uwsgi-django running in a docker container. The default django page loads just fine outside the container as expected, but i'm seeing in the logs the nginx keeps stopping and getting restarted with a new process id. That worries me, like I've messed up a config somewhere. Of course I come here, and see my issue, with no answer 1 year later *sob*

Comment: I'm having similiar issues as well running inside of a docker container.   If a solution is found it would be great.